# ASP.NET MVC timed actions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pop3, openpop

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 project where I process emails too via Pop3 protocol. I use the OpenPop.NET package to parse the emails, but I do not find any method in that to check the emails by time. What is the best solution to check the email account every minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem once where I had to update the cache of an application periodically.
Quartz.NET did a good job for that. They provide a range of tutorials on the project page.

http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/